# Proving the Borell-Cantelli Lemma by martingale convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, ergodic-theory

I got stuck on an exercise (Exercise 5.2.1) from the book:
Ergodic Theory: with view towards Number Theory By Manfred Leopold Einsiedler and Thomas Ward.

In the book they presented the following theorem.

**Theorem:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a prob. space and $(\mathcal{F}_n,n\geq 1)$ an increasing sequence of $\sigma-$algebras, $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\cup\mathcal{F}_n)$. If $f\in L^1(\mathcal{A},\mu)$, then:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f|\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathbb{E}[f|\mathcal{F}],$$
where the convergence is almost sure and in $L^1$.

And then the exercise asked for a proof of the following version of the Borell-Cantelli Lemma:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a prob. space and $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of independent measurable sets. Then if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)=\infty$ it holds that $$\mu(\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}A_n)=1.$$

I already achieved to apply the martingale convergence theorem to show that for $A:=\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}A_n$, we  get $\mu(A)=\mathcal{X}(A)$ so especially $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$.

But my question is now how I can prove that it actually holds $\mu(A)=1$ using the condition $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)=\infty$.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Okay I think the following should work.
Just assume $\mu(A)=0$ then we get
$0=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mu(\cup_{n\geq N}A_n)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$ and this contradicts the assumption $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)=\infty$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $N$. Then $\sum_{n \ge N} \mu(A_n) = \infty$ implies \begin{align*} 0 &=  \prod_{n \ge N} (1-\mu(A_n)) \\ &= \prod_{n \ge N} \mu(A_n^c) \\ &= \mu(\cap_{n \ge N} A_n^c) \\ &= \mu\left((\cup_{n \ge N} A_n)^c\right) \\ &= 1-\mu(\cup_{n \ge N} A_n).\end{align*} As this holds for all $N$, we see $\mu(\cap_N \cup_{n \ge N} A_n) = 1$.

Comment: First of all tahnks for the answer, but I stillt got a question:
In the last line there should be a $1-\mu(\cup_{n\geq N}A_n)$ and not a equal 1 at the end, right?
And I am confused how you directly get the first equal sign out of the condition?

The standard proof I know is using a similar argument to show that $\mu(\cap_{n\geq N} A_n^c=0$ and then conclude. But since I wanted to use the martingale conv. theorem and already got $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$ doing that would make the first part redundant.

Comment: @Vincent Edited the typo. For the first equality, I am just using the basic fact that if a sequence of positive real numbers has $\sum_n x_n = \infty$, then the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x_n) = 0$.